# Get last x bytes from file in zip archive

Tags: php, file, byte

I need to read the last 8 bytes from a .jpg File which users can upload to my webserver (using PHP File POST) to validate them. To make it a bit more complicated, the .jpg is stored inside of a ZIP file.

Current code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($file['tmp_name']) === True) {
  $img = $zip->getFromName('thumb.jpg');
  if($img !== False) { //If image exists
    //TODO: add file check
  }
```

How can I properly check if the last 8 bytes equal (Java)

```
new byte[]{0,1,1,2,3,5,8};
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up ZipArchive::getStream

Comment: @DragonYen my problem is that the returned Stream is not seekable, so I have no idea how to get the last n bytes.

Comment: Could you read some number of characters from the file until EOF -- then check the last 8 characters of the "buffer" (string) you were using to read the file?

Comment: @DragonYen The Problem is that I can't get the filesize of the stream either :/ Found a different solution though. Thanks!